# Comma separator confusion in Array and ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Why am I getting an error while initializing `ArrayList` with a trailing comma (,) whereas I understand through various websites that `Array` with trailing comma(s) will create holes and iterating that will skip the holes?

Java:

```java
class ProblemA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //HashMap<Integer,Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> map = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,2,3,2,));
    int[] arr = {1,2,2,3,2,};
    }
}
```

[image: Java code in ArrayList]

Comment: Arrays.asList is a method invocation.  `int[] arr` is an array declaration.  They are simply two separate things.  The fact that they both use commas does not make them the same thing.  And there are no “holes” in an array or in method parameters.

Comment: Why should `ArrayList` work the same way as arrays? They are completely different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> hereas I understand through various websites that Array with trailing comma(s) will create holes and iterating that will skip the holes

Not in java it doesn't. That's referring to various other languages where you can e.g. type `[, , ,]` and this makes a list of 4x "nothing". But java doesn't have that - the closest thing to nothing that java has is `null`, but you'd have to type it out. `List.of(null, null, null, null)` would make 'a list of 4x nothing' in java, as near as can be.

### So what about java's trailing commas

As per the java language spec, in method invocations, you can't just toss a pointless and completely optional comma at the end of an arguments list. It's simply not valid java. However, when writing an array initializer, you CAN do that. Why? Just cuz. Spec says so. At some point your question boils down to: "What was the language designer thinking" - which is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow. You'd have to ask them.

At any rate, you are allowed to do it, and **it does nothing at all**. There is zero difference between `int[] x = {1,2,};` and `int[] x = {1,2};`. Both produce a 2-sized array with elements `1` and `2`. The trailing comma is completely optional and has absolutely no effect. Whatsoever. Identical class files. Go ahead, try it, compile it, run a byte-differ on the class files that come out. Identical.

### But... why?

The reason trailing commas are convenient at times is because of **version control systems**. Stop thinking about writing 5 lines of script and your first programming lessons for a moment - think working in a bigger team, producing a product that hundreds of thousands of users depend on, where billions of euros just go up in smoke if e.g. a security issue is plaguing the code base.

You want to be capable of working together in teams, which means not all code you look at is written by you, neccessarily. That means you may want to, for any given line, ask the system: Hey, who last changed this line, and can you show me the other stuff they did around that time, and it would be even better if I can see a comment or a link to a ticket in a ticketing system that explains why they did all this, because I need that context to know what's happening.

The solution to that is version control systems, where you 'check in', as a unit of work, a bunch of modifications to existing source files. "Today, I added these 5 lines here, removed these 2 lines here, changed these 2 lines, and added these 2 whole new files. That whole thing comprises the fix for the bug mentioned in ticket 12894". That sort of thing.

Once you have that, you get a convenient route for code review: That your edits aren't just pushed straight into what powers, say, `google.com`, but that someone else first tests this out and looks at your changes; a second pair of eyes. They can look at exactly what you changed.

And only now can you understand the point of optional trailing commas. They do absolutely nothing, but imagine you have a list of, say, known US states. You might have:

```
String[] STATES = {
  "Alabama",
  "Arkansas",
  "New york"
};
```

and then someone wants to add a new state to the list, so they edit that code:

```
String[] STATES = {
  "Alabama",
  "Arkansas",
  "New york",
  "Hawaii"
};
```

The problem is, technically they changed **2** lines there. They changed the `New York` line, by adding a comma. That 'noises it all up'.

Let's say I notice that its a bit odd they didn't spell it `New York` - that Y is customarily capitalized. Possibly some other system requires that it's all lowercase except the first letter, perhaps. I want to see who edited/made that New york line, what ticket is associated with it, and when it happened. So I ask the system and I get.... your edit. The one that added Hawaii - the one that is utterly irrelevant. Only because of that silly trailing comma. A code reviewer will also have to review that edit which also seems pointless.

Imagine instead that we have a policy of always using that pointless trailing comma that does nothing at all, and we started with:

```
String[] STATES = {
  "Alabama",
  "Arkansas",
  "New york",
};
```

instead. Now I can add that Hawaii line (adding a pointless trailing comma), and now I haven't noised it up. My 'commit' (list of changes I made, it's a term of art in the Version Control System world) is just the one line adding hawaii, nothing more.

That's the **only** reason that java, or any other language, allows this concept of 'trailing commas in comma separated lists that do not actually do anything'. They do not create holes or an extra entry. They exist only to keep commits as clean as they can be.

You may correctly conclude I dislike the fact that you can't put trailing commas in method invocations. I'll make a point to mention this when the opportunity arises in amber-dev or what not - I'm pretty sure the structure of the language spec can handle it.